# Adding to an installation project in visual studio installation of WinPcap

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation-package

recently i was working on a project with the dll of pcapDotNet
(here is their site: https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).

now I want to make an installation of my project.
I figured out that when i insall my project on other computers which winPcap weren't installed in them the program will crush.

So my questions are:

1. How can i add the installation of winPcap 4.1.2 to my installation?
2. How can i check if that installation is required or not and act accordingly?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

all right, 
so i figured out how to do it my self.
you need to download boot strapper manifest generator
(downloaded it from here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Bootstrapper-Manifest-Generator.shtml)
this program make a boot strapper out of your .exe file and make a Pre-requisite package.
there is a tutorial on how to use it here:
http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2011/03/03/bootstrap-manifest-generator-2008-how-to-guide-v2/

hope that helps others :)